# >=sysdate-30 business day's data pick in oracle

Tags: oracle

I need to pick sysdate- 30 business days data from table test.

when i am doing 
select * from test 
where cre_d>=sysdate-30;

it will include the saturday,sunday and US holidays if any.I want to pick sysdate- 30 business days(idealy sysdate-38 because 4 weekend came in a week but its not looks correct because US holidays may came and this sysdate-38 should change with sysdate-39.)

Kindly suggest the best way to doing this.Thanks!

Comment: is the list of busniess days in a month stored in the database

Answer (score 0):

`CREATE TABLE t_tb AS
 SELECT sysdate-level AS dt 
FROM dual CONNECT BY level < 50;`

`SELECT TO_CHAR(dt,'d'),
  dt
   FROM t_tb
  WHERE TO_CHAR(dt,'d') BETWEEN 2 AND 6and rownum <= 30`

Is that you want?